# ¿Como llevo una imagen al frente de la cámara en Unity 2D?

Tags: unity

resulta que tengo un cubo que refleja lo que muestra la webcam, pero quiero que por arriba del cubo se muestre una imagen y no me resulta.
Adjunto foto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que configurar la posición en Z del GameObject.
Adicional a eso también seria bueno colocarle un valor mayor a 0 en el order in layer de la imagen para las prioridades en pantalla en caso de tener varias con el mismo valor en profundidad(en Z)